# Using Identity Transform, target one specific node

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to replace one specific instance of a `<Status>` node, and not the rest in the document.

How can I target this path?

Basically I'm inside an `<Order_Order>` and I need to target `Order_Order/Status`.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />      
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RunProcessor">
  <RunProcessor>true</RunProcessor>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Status">
  <Status>Dispatched</Status>
</xsl:template>
```

Example I'm pulling from:

```
<Order_Order>
<Version>v1_0</Version>
<ValidationMessages/>
<FullSerialize>true</FullSerialize>
<ID>7d89105f-586d-4a5d-</ID>
<OrderTypeID>Order</OrderTypeID>
<AccountID>1015</AccountID>    
<Notes/>
<DeliveryNotes/>
<Status>Shipped</Status>
   Order_Entries>
      <Order_Entry>
       <Version>v1_0</Version>
       <Status>Shipped</Status>
        <ID>4d393f51-1082-417a-83d0</ID>
```

I just want to target that first < Status > node, and NOT update the second one (or any of the other ones there are)

==================================EDIT===================================

The solution was presented below. Very simply I was able to specify the path in the template match:

```
<xsl:template match="Order_Order/Status">
<Status>Dispatched</Status>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Can you add an example input and output? ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: I added an example of what I'm pulling from.

Comment: If you use the identity transformation template as the starting point and want to manipulate `Order_Order/Status` then add a template matching that node e.g. `<xsl:template match="Order_Order/Status"><xsl:copy>Changed</xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.

Comment: So I would basically just add the path straight to the template match then?

    <xsl:template match="Order_Order/Status">
    <xsl:copy>Dispatched</xsl:copy>
    </xsl‌​:template>

Comment: Yes, simply do that, a pattern is a path. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#pattern-examples for some examples and then just experiment. If in doubt, read the formal spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#NT-Pattern.

Comment: @StanleySinger If you want to target only the first `Status` node (first in what? Its parent `Order_Entry`? Its ancestor `Order_Order`? The entire document?) then please show us an example that has more than one `Status` and include the expected result.